# OpenVPN vpn chaining

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vpn-client, point-to-site-vpn

### Background

I have two networks:

- Home network
- Servers network

My home's network contains a VPN server. My Servers network contain another VPN server.

The only way to my computer to log into the server's network is by creating a VPN connection to the home network first. Then, create another VPN connection to the server's network. So it looks like this:

```
My laptop ==> Home network ==> Servers network.
```

The server's network has a firewall rule that denied any connection outside the home network.

I'm using OpenVPN GUI (Windows) to log in to my VPN servers. *When I'm on the right network, I can create a new tunnel for each VPN (separately) without any problem.*

### The Question

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to connect those two VPN networks one after another. Like, chaining the tunnels in order to be in the Servers network.

I saw that my `ovpn` files contain configurations. What is the current configuration of my case?

Comment: Why don't you just make a VPN connection to the server's network?

Comment: Can't. It's locked by firewall rule. Allowed connection can come only from Home network.

Comment: Why on earth is your VPN blocked by a firewall? That you can certainly fix.

Comment: We can talk about this question, but this not what I've asked...